NestJs DTO Validation in a Monorepo Setup
I am new to the NestJs ecosystem and developing a NestJS App in a mono repo setup. My Nest app is in a package of its own while the DTOs are in a separate package as well such that the Client App can also have access to the DTOs without depending on the backend. Currently, I have tried validation with class-validator and zod with their corresponding pipes (I've settled for zod).
My issue now is that I want to be able to validate for example a UserDto to determine if the value of an email has been registered before. In class-validator, I can create a new ValidationConstraintInterface and then use it in my DTO and in zod I can use the refine() method and pass a function that does the actual validation. So far, both cases pose a challenge because both the ValidConstrantInterface and zod's refine() methods require access to the database which currently only the NestJs app has access to and I would like to keep it so.
So is there a way to push the validation to the NestJs pipeline in the NestJs App so that my DTO package remains unaware of the database? I'd prefer a solution for zod but I also don't mind a solution for class-validator as a last resort.
